# Sharepoint 2013 Client Object Model Console Application the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden-error

Tags: console-application, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-clientobject

I have SharePoint 2013 WebApp with Claim Based Authentication. This WebApp also has trusted identity provided enabled at it. Now I am trying to connect to one of the site collection from the Console application with below code.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url)) 

{

       var rootweb = clientContext.Web;
       clientContext.Load(rootweb );
       clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Every time on execution I gets the error:
**the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden-error**
even with the below peace of code

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("SiteURL"))

{

    CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
    NetWorkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"); 

    cc.Add(new Uri("http://localhost"), "Negotiate", nc));

    context.Credentials = cc; 

    Web web = context.Web;
     context.Load(web);

    Log.Debug("Loading web.");
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
}
```

The error remains the same. the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden-error.

Please suggest what shall I do to avoid the above error

Answer (score 0):

The credential cache seems to be your problem.  Try this example instead:

```
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://Your.Site.Url"))
        {
            context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I am trying with same still not working. Env is SP2016 OnPremise